# Code Coverage on Java Remote VM

Tags: java, eclipse, jvm, code-coverage, eclemma

How can I get (if it is even possible) the code coverage report running on a remote JAVA VM in Eclipse

So I have a Unit test Suite running over the clients (for simplicity VM1) of the service layer (VM2). (The project was already setup this way and it is too deep in to re-architect that part)

Debug works if i add a port listener as follows:

```
<jvmFlag>-Xdebug</jvmFlag>
<jvmFlag>-Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=1044,server=y,suspend=y</jvmFlag>
```

So was hoping to do something similar for a code coverage tool like EclEmma.

The backend services architecture looks a lot like this:
https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/appengine-modules-sample-java

I am suspecting would need to be adding some kind of hook on my service layer as well. (maybe in the parent maven file)

Comment: From this:
https://github.com/jacoco/jacoco/wiki/MavenMultiModule

Does not seem like it is possible.

Answer (score 2):

You can start JaCoCo (code coverage engine behind Eclipse EclEmma plugin) in a "tcpserver" mode - see option "output" at page  http://www.jacoco.org/jacoco/trunk/doc/agent.html

And connect to it

- from EclEmma - http://www.eclemma.org/userdoc/importexport.html
- Ant Task - http://www.jacoco.org/jacoco/trunk/doc/ant.html
- Maven - http://www.jacoco.org/jacoco/trunk/doc/dump-mojo.html