# How to run remote code coverage in eclipse? like there is remote debugging, is there a way for remote code coverage?

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, code-coverage, remote-debugging

I want to see code coverage of a remote tomcat server in eclipse. I am able to debug it remotely via eclipse. I am able to do the code coverage when tomcat is in eclipse.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/43875417/6505250

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Code Coverage on Java Remote VM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43821402/code-coverage-on-java-remote-vm)